# Matplotlib: x-axis Scientific notation power not readable

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted the x-axis in scientific notation, however 10^(**this**) "**this**" is not readable:

It gets even worse once I save it as a png:

[image: hard to see power symbol]

I am using **GoogleColab**.

### EDIT A reproducible example

The dataframe:

```
      max_VG  total_dose uG  time_plot_color
0    1.23599  0.000          25.349         
10   1.23740  0.000          45.743         
20   1.23584  14214.736      6.107          
30   1.23212  49751.576      26.516         
40   1.23427  53305.260      46.810         
50   1.23227  82905.740      7.137          
60   1.22827  156906.940     27.457         
70   1.23081  156906.940     47.839         
80   1.22877  213017.740     8.149          
90   1.22450  325239.340     28.436         
100  1.22849  325239.340     48.802         
110  1.22595  401273.540     9.145          
120  1.22225  538135.100     29.494         
130  1.22687  538135.100     49.902         
140  1.22438  652308.380     10.241         
150  1.22174  823568.300     30.597         
160  1.22662  823568.300     51.021
```

I am using the **holder** variable  and **exec function** as a placeholder so I can use the same template figure in multiple plots

```py
class TemplatePlots: 
  def __init__(self, plot):
    self.plot=plot
  def template_simple (self, ax_label='x', ay_label='y', title=None ):    
   #set up the figure
    
    fig, (ax) = plt.subplots(1, sharex=True, figsize=(14,7))
    fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=16)
    ax.set_xlabel(ax_label, fontsize=14, color='blue')
    ax.set_ylabel(ay_label, fontsize=14, color='blue')
    ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0) , useMathText=True)
    ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0) , useMathText=True)
    
    #the actual plot 
    exec(self.plot)
    
    plt.show()
    

holder='''
plt.scatter(df['total_dose uG'], df['max_VG'], 
c= df['time_plot_color']), 
clb = plt.colorbar()
clb.ax.set_title('time(s)')
'''

temp=TemplatePlots(holder)
temp.template_simple(ax_label='total_dose uG', ay_label='maxVG (V)', title=f"MaxVG vs Dose:  {maxVG['file'].iloc[0]}")
```

Comment: Share the complete code (or at least a code to generate a similar plot where the problem can be observed), I think you can solve this by changing the figsize and the dpi when saving.

Comment: Something is very strange about your output. It should look much more like the one seen in the examples, e.g. [this one](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_scales.html), where numbers are clearly readable. How exactly do you run the code? What is your output format?

Comment: I thought it was a simple fix so didn't put the whole example. updating now.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am running in google colab, is there any other information I need to add?

Comment: @Mathieu How should I change the figsize ? make it smaller?

Comment: The updated image looks ok, doesn't it? But in general your figure size looks pretty large. I would half the figure size and double the dpi.

Comment: the 10^6 is still pretty small, can I control that directly ? How do I double the dpi?

Comment: I changed the figsize to (10,6), but it hasn't really gotten any better

Comment: Try a dpi of 144 or higher

Comment: That solved it! thanks!